# Does inserting the "break" in the for loop negatively interfere with it?

Tags: break

This class catches an input "zip code" from the main class. I am supposed to find the "catch digit" of whatever zip code was entered, meaning the number added to the sum of the numbers in the zip code that makes it divisible by 10. However, regardless of the zip code I input, it returns 10 as the catch digit every time. I was wondering if it had something to do with the "break" that I put into the for loop.

```
public class Digit {

    Digit() {
    }

    public int findCheckDigit(String zipCode) {
        int firstDigit = Integer.parseInt(zipCode.substring(0,1));
        int secondDigit = Integer.parseInt(zipCode.substring(1,2));
        int thirdDigit = Integer.parseInt(zipCode.substring(2,3));
        int fourthDigit = Integer.parseInt(zipCode.substring(3,4));
        int fifthDigit = Integer.parseInt(zipCode.substring(4,5));
        int sumOfDigits = firstDigit + secondDigit + thirdDigit + fourthDigit + fifthDigit;
        int check = 0;

        for(check = 0; check < 10; check += 1) {
            int remainder = sumOfDigits % 10;
            if(remainder == 0) {
                break;
            }
        }

        return check;
    }
}
```

Comment: In those cases the break statement is not reached. If you enter a code like `12322` then `break` will be reached.

Comment: Your `for` loop repeats the exact same computation every time.  It's useless to make it a loop.

Comment: Is it Java? Add the language tag.

Answer (score 0):

I give you a sample to refer:

```
public int findCheckDigit(String zipCode){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < zipCode.length(); i++) {
        sum+=Integer.parseInt(zipCode.substring(i,i+1));
        if(sum%10==0){
            return i+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

As for your code, your didn't iterate you zipcode digits at all. you just calculated sumOfDigits % 10 for 10 times except the sum of first 5 dig is just 10.